# SSDT/SSIS Execute SQL Task not populating variable with query output

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

My `Execute SQL Task` uses a simple query that should be returning a single value.  I want to write that value to a variable so that I can use it in a data flow task later but the result never seems to get written to my variable.

The SQL statement is simple:

```
 select max (rec_id) from [dbo].[RX_BILLING_TEST]
```

and I believe that I've set up the task correctly:

[image: General tab settings from exec SQL task]

[image: Result Set tab setting from exec SQL task]

When I execute the task, it completes successfully but the variables window shows that the value of my variable didn't update. I set breakpoints on variable value changed and on post execute but that didn't help.

As much as I hate errors, this is a case where I would appreciate getting one to point me in some direction.  Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: When your package finishes running, the variable goes back to the design time state. What are you going to do with this value? If you, for example, write it to a database or pop it up with a messagebox you'll probably find it is being populated.

Comment: What Nick said. Inspect the variable during runtime to verify it is not being set. A couple ways you can do this. Add a script task and use Messagebox.Show(Dts.Variables("YourVariable").Value) or set a breakpoint and put a watch on the variable.

Comment: Just use breakpoint and watch window to see the change, break at post status

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  My intent is to use the value as part of an expression in a data flow task but I haven't gotten that far yet.  I was already watching the variable with a breakpoint and the value doesn't seem to change.  I don't know VB or C# but I tried creating a messagebox from a C# ScriptTask -- System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The value of RecID is " + Dts.Variables["User::RecID"].Value); -- but that throws an error...

Comment: at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)...

Comment: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()  Not sure if it's worth doing anything with this one... I really just want to variable value for the next task.

Comment: you showed the stack trace without the error message

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case there are many things you have to check:

- Try adding an alias to the aggregate function

  ```
  select max (rec_id) AS Max_Rec_Id from [dbo].[RX_BILLING_TEST]
  ```
- Check that your package doesn't have more than one variable `User::v_Recid` with different scopes. or that `User::v_Recid` scope's is `Execute SQL Task`. (it must be the `Package`)
- Test your SQL Command using Sql Server Management Studio
- Try adding the database name to your Command

  ```
  select max (rec_id) AS Max_Rec_Id from [MyDB].[dbo].[RX_BILLING_TEST]
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  My package only has the one variable and its scope is set for the package.  SQL runs fine in SSMS.  Aliasing, fully qualifying the database object -- doesn't make a difference.

Comment: i faced a same issue, and i found that it was a 2 variable with a same name issue, when i clicked on the `Execute SQL Task` the second package will appear in the variables list. so the variable of scope `execute sql task` get the value and the other still null

Comment: I mean the second variable appear in the variables window

Comment: Okay, just to close the loop on this one.  Out of frustration, I went ahead and created a new Execute SQL task using, using the same select statement and same task parameters -- it works as expected.  I still have no idea why my original task didn't update the variable...which is really annoying but not the end of the world.    Thanks again for everyone's input.

Comment: @cgchu what your solution is a workaround but it confirm what i am talkung about, when you delete the Execute Sql Task it deletes the variable having it as scope. Happy to get ur issue solved

Comment: @cgchu if you don't agree with me add ur own answer. Else u have to accept mine. Good luck

Comment: Hi Hadi, I'm not convinced that we know what the answer is.  As I mentioned originally, there's only one variable for the entire package.  Even when I created a new task, I still used vRecID as my variable.  I just disabled the old task when I created a new one.